# Añadir imagenes SVG en aplicaciones Android

Tags: android, svg

Hola muy buen día a todos, he estado buscando y veo que es posible trabajar con imágenes svg, pero lamentablemente no sé que sucede que no muestra la imagen vectorial, solo me muestra el fondo que le establezco, es posible que me puedan ayudar con esto?

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente usas [SVG Android](https://code.google.com/archive/p/svg-android/source)

no comentas algún error, simplemente no muestra la imagen vectorial; hay que [deshabilitar la aceleración de hardware para la vista en tiempo de ejecución](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html).

```
myImageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Esa puede ser la diferencia, ya que tu dispositivo seguramente tiene habilitada esa propiedad por default.

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.android_head);
myImageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
myImageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

De esa forma podrás visualizar sin ningún problema la imagen SVG.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias Elenasys, efectivamente era esa línea de código que faltaba.

Comment: Que bien!, de hecho yo también tuve este problema, saludos!.