# Usar letras de material design como vectores en aplicación con Android Studio

Tags: android, array, svg

Quiero usar algunas letras de [Material Letter Icons](https://github.com/eladnava/material-letter-icons#material-letter-icons) como imágenes (vectores) en una app que estoy desarrollando en Android Studio.

Lo que hago es guardar el código svg de [cualquiera de las letras](https://github.com/eladnava/material-letter-icons/tree/master/dist/svg) en un archivo y luego desde Android Studio colocándome en la carpeta `drawable` selecciono en el menú contextual: `New/Vector Asset/Local file (SVG, PSD)`.

Luego busco mi archivo en el equipo y lo selecciono.

Me muestra el círculo, pero jamás la Letra, tal como se puede ver en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A pesar de eso termino de crear mi drawable con la esperanza de poder ver la letra al usarlo en el código... pero no, la letra no se muestra, solamente el círculo.

El código del archivo que trato de incluir en Android Studio es este:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="532" height="532" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <circle cx="255" cy="255" r="230" fill="#304ffe" />
    <text x="255" y="246" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" font-size="275" font-weight="100" font-family="Roboto">L</text>
</svg>
```

En [esta pregunta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46972625/5587982) comentan que los vectores de Android Studio trabajan con paths... parece ser cierto, porque por ejemplo este svg sí puedo incluirlo en `drawable` sin problemas:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<g transform="matrix(1.25 0 0 -1.25 0 45)">
    <g>
        <g>
            <path style="fill:#DD2E44;" d="M409.6-328.089c0-25.134-20.378-45.511-45.511-45.511H45.511C20.378-373.6,0-353.222,0-328.089
                V-9.511C0,15.622,20.378,36,45.511,36h318.578C389.222,36,409.6,15.622,409.6-9.511V-328.089z"/>
            <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M273.294-168.811c0,44.055-22.938,83.74-68.449,83.74s-68.437-39.686-68.437-83.74
                c0-44.407,22.198-83.729,68.437-83.729C251.096-252.54,273.294-213.219,273.294-168.811 M79.61-168.811
                c0,75.73,50.972,133.985,125.235,133.985c73.182,0,125.247-60.075,125.247-133.985c0-75.355-50.62-133.962-125.247-133.962
                C130.947-302.773,79.61-244.166,79.61-168.811"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Como se puede ver, éste último (correspondiente a la letra **O**) sí que usa paths, mientras que el otro, sumamente claro y entendible para nosotros los humanos, usa la letra **L**. El hecho es que no tengo ni idea sobre esto de los paths, parece que cada letra se representa con un valor. Tampoco dispongo de un programa para crear svg.

¿Hay alguna manera de poder lograr que se muestre la letra? ¿O conocen alguna otra manera de poder usar letras de Material Design como vectores en una aplicación.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda, se trata de un elemento fundamental para este proyecto.

Comment: puede que te interese eso https://github.com/akashandroid90/ImageLetterIcon o bien esa otra librería https://github.com/alirezaafkar/TextDrawable/

Comment: El primer .svg que corresponde a la letra "L" es para uso exclusivo en web que en realidad carga una fuente, mientras que la letra "O" es un .svg que dibuja mediante lineas la letra "O". Te recomiendo este visor online: https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/svg-viewer-editor.html

Comment: Los paths en realidad son lineas con cierto grosor y color, la forma adecuada para convertir un .SVG a una imagen vectorial (.xml) para su uso en aplicaciones Android debe ser el mismo Android Studio. Como comentario existen convertidores online aunque muestran una imagen similar en ocasiones generan paths innecesarios.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En efecto, android studio acepta imagenes vectoriales de forma nativa pero tiene limitantes. En este caso, el codigo

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="532" height="532" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <circle cx="255" cy="255" r="230" fill="#304ffe" />
    <text x="255" y="246" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" font-size="275" font-weight="100" font-family="Roboto">L</text>
</svg>
```

no es soportado. Lo que se debe hacer es tranformar dicho vector SVG a una imagen vectorial que soporte android studio. hay un par de herramientas en linea que hacen este trabajo

http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/
http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/

A pesar de ello, me doy cuenta que la tranformacion esta generan que las letras no quedan centradas con lo cual no creo que sea el efecto que esperas.

Ya hablando de otra estrategia, cuando me enfrento a este tipo de disenos, suelo usar un layout combinado con un shape para generar el mismo efecto, y asi no tener que importar un svg por cada letra. Esto te lo muestro a continuacion.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
        android:text="HS"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Y la imagen circle_shape es asi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDar"/>
</shape>
```

el efecto logrado es este

[image: circulas shape]

De esta manera, puedes cambiar las letras como gustes de la forma que gustes, incluso de forma programatica, cosa que no se puede importando un vector para cada letra. Y si quieres cambiar el font, solo debes descargarla e importarla a tu proyecto y cambiarle el fonto a ese textview en especifico lo cual ya es posible.

Espero que estas alternativas sean de utilidad para ti

Comment: Interesante la opción personalizada que comentas y la posibilidad de cambiarla de forma programática. Probaré y te comentaré el resultado.

Comment: Si esta respuesta es de ayuda te agradeciera que le dieras un punto, o en caso que la cosideres como correcta la marques como tal. No te olvides de dar este feedback a la comunidad :D :D

Comment: Lo resolví como indicas en la 2ª parte de la respuesta, sólo que tuve que darle un tamaño al `shape`, porque no se veía redondo. Quedó así más o menos: `<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="#C51162"/>
    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp"/>
</shape>`. Me pareció una solución óptima, de ese modo no recargo la app con librerías de terceros. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Inicio comentando que el primer acercamiento para [usar SVG en android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7307/a%C3%B1adir-imagenes-svg-en-aplicaciones-android) fue mediante [SVG Android](https://code.google.com/archive/p/svg-android/source):

Actualmente se pueden usar en tu aplicación sin necesidad de libraries, para usar los .svg dentro de un proyecto android es necesario agregarlos a tu proyecto como [**Vector Asset**](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html),

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí un ejemplo:

[Incorporar svg en android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131720/incorporar-svg-en-android/131724#131724)

En realidad el uso de vectores se indica para imágenes que no requiere de generar muchos vectores ya que el trabajo de esta generación la toma el procesador.

Es recomendable para este tipo de fuente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no para este tipo de fuente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto a porque no se muestra, la razón es que debes convertirla a Vector Asset que tiene una estructura similar a :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M20,11H7.83l5.59,-5.59L12,4l-8,8 8,8 1.41,-1.41L7.83,13H20v-2z"/>
</vector>
```

Se transforma de `<svg` a `<vector`

En tu `build.gradle` debes agregar:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
      vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

y usar `app:srcCompat` :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/letter_a"/>
```

**Pero en el caso de los .svg de fuentes que tratas de cargar en realidad son para web, no para uso en una aplicación Android por esa razón no se muestra en la aplicación**:

```html
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="532" height="532" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <circle cx="255" cy="255" r="230" fill="#00bfa5" />
    <text x="255" y="246" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" font-size="275" font-weight="100" font-family="Roboto">A</text>
</svg>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como opción puedes [convertir los .png a .svg](http://pngtosvg.com/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y de esta forma obtener el .svg para convertirlo a vector asset y usarlo en tu aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano el problema es que el .svg es para web, la opción es convertirlo de .png a .svg ( me gusta usar: http://pngtosvg.com/ ), en donde este .svg , de esta forma lo puedes convertir a vector asset y usarlo en tu app. Es que anteriormente mi nombre de usuario era Elenasys :-)