# ¿Es posible cambiar el color a un elemento «shape» de forma programática en Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Gracias a la respuesta a esta pregunta: [Usar letras de material design como vectores en aplicación con Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/138401/29967) he podido crear un `TextView` con una letra y un fondo al estilo Material Design.

El `TextView` sería este:

```
      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewMaterial"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="-50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:textColor="@color/transparent"
            android:textSize="65dp"
             />
```

Los elementos que cambian en el mismo son pasados a través de un Adapter, del siguiente modo:

```
arrayList.add(new BreviarioRecyclerAdapter("Oficio+Laudes", R.drawable.shape_red, colorGrupo1,"M"));
arrayList.add(new BreviarioRecyclerAdapter("Oficio", R.drawable.shape_green, colorGrupo1,"O"));
arrayList.add(new BreviarioRecyclerAdapter("Laudes", R.drawable.shape_amber, colorGrupo1,"L"));
//...
```

Aquí paso tres elementos distintos con valores cambiantes:

- Texto que iría fuera (texto del item)
- El elemento `shape`
- El color de fondo del item, no del shape
- La letra que iría dentro del círculo

En el Adapter, yo establezco los valores respectivos del siguiente modo:

```
textView.setText(item.text); //texto del item
textViewMaterial.setBackgroundResource(item.drawable); //shape
relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(item.color); //color de fondo del item
textViewMaterial.setText(item.letra); //letra en el círculo
```

La cuestión es que **cada vez tengo que pasarle un shape en específico**: `shape_red, shape_green, shape_amber...`.

**¿Habría alguna forma de usar un solo `shape`, y pasarle el color de fondo como un parámetro más a través del Adapter para luego establecer ese color de forma programática?**

Los `shape` son todos así:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="#f44336"/>
    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp"/>
</shape>
```

Lo único que cambia es el elemento `android:color` en cada caso, por lo que creo que sería factible usar un solo `shape` que pueda cambiar de forma dinámica, pero no sé cómo podría hacerlo.

Comment: Has pensado creando el drawable por codigo y no utilizando un recurso?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823451/set-android-shape-color-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

Esto lo requerí hace unos días, en realidad este método funciona:

[Cambiar el color de un `Shape` programaticamente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823451/set-android-shape-color-programmatically), realizado por [Vikram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2558882/vikram)

Mi vista tenia configurado un "shape":

```
android:background="@drawable/myRoundBackground"
```

Para cambiar el color, se obtiene el "background" actual de la vista, se obtiene que tipo de instancia es, en este caso siempre sería `GradientDrawable`, y se procede a configurar el color.

```
Drawable background = imageView.getBackground();    

if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {   
    ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = (ShapeDrawable) background;
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.myColor));
} else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) background;
    gradientDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.myColor));
} else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) background;
    colorDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.myColor));
}
```

de esta forma, todas mis vistas cambiaron al color deseado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En cuanto pueda lo pruebo y te comento el resultado...